# Is it ok to have a GNU Make target that claims to generate / update a certain target file but actually doesn't?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

At present, I have a makefile that has:

- a target which links an executable image file from a bunch of object files
- a pattern rule target that compiles the various object files the linker target depends on

I want to make the following changes.

1. Instead of compiling the object files outright, I want the pattern rule target mentioned above to create (for each object file that needs updating) an empty ***object_file_name*.update** file. Essentially, this target's job would be to take stock of all object files that actually need to be recompiled.
2. Write a new target that launches a Perl process which finds all these ***object_file_name*.update** files and, for each object file that must be recompiled, compiles it in this Perl process.

I know how to do **2)** ... that part is not giving me any trouble. The part I'm worried about is **1)**. The reason is that that target would basically have to *claim* to update any needed object files while, in truth, merely creating an **.update** file for each such object file but not the object file itself.

I think I could trick GNU Make into not starting to try to link anything before all the object files have been built by declaring my dependencies accordingly (pseudo-code, not a valid GNU Make snippet):

```
# Phony target that reads the *.update files created by the pattern rule target below and then
# compiles each object file for which an *.update file exists.
COMPILE_OBJECTS : 
   ...

# Pattern rule target to take stock of all object files that need updating. Creates an *.update file for
# each object file that needs recompiling. 
%.o : %.c :
   ...

$(EXE_FILE_TO_LINK) : $(LIST_OF_OBJECT_FILE_PATHS) COMPILE_OBJECTS
   ...
```

but I still worry that this might result in undefined behavior because my pattern rule target would basically be lying to GNU Make about updating the needed object files. Is my worry justified?

Basically, I want to interject an intermediate layer between GNU Make and the compiler so that GNU Make doesn't compile each object file separately. Instead, the compiling would be done in a single Perl process that has access to the complete list of object files that need to be compiled, allowing me to do various fancy things that I couldn't do if GNU Make controlled compilation directly.

Comment: I would use `$?` automatic variable that is _the names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them_.

Comment: Um question though. Why do you compile in a single process? You have more than one CPU, right?

Comment: @bobbogo The Perl program that controls compilation has the ability to delegate compilation to a pool of subprocesses (one for each logical core the machine has), so we do make use of all available cores.

Comment: Nice. (Personally I would always use _make_'s facilities for running things in parallel. It is straight forward to get your perl to talk to _make_'s jobserver so that the parallelism chosen by _make_'s `-j` flag is honoured everywhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's legal and I often use this pattern.

Consider the case where you only want to kick off a long build step if a file has changed.

```
target: config-file
    target-creator $< -o $@
```

Now let's say we can't give *make* the dependencies for `config-file` (because the config file creation step lacks a dependency listing ability (BAH!)).

```
.PHONY: FORCE
FORCE: ;

config-file: FORCE
    config-creator -o $@.tmp
    cmp $@.tmp $@ || mv $@.tmp $@
```

- We ask *make* to build `target`

  - *Make* first has to build `config-file`

    - *Make* will *always* run the recipe for `config-file`,
      as its dependency `FORCE` is out of date (being phony)
    - **CRUCIALLY** we only update `config-file` if `config-creator` decides something has actually changed

      - If *cmp* decides `config-file.tmp` and `config-file` are the same, and the last line of the recipe completes with no error
      - OTOH if *cmp* detects a mis-compare, it fails, and the shell goes on to execute the *mv*.
  - After running the recipe for `config-file`, *make* does actually check `config-file`'s modification time. **IF** `config-file` has become younger than `target`, only then will `target-creator` be run.

The subtlety here is that even though `config-file`'s recipe runs every time, `config-file` itself is not phony.

Comment: That is pretty darn clever! :D I wish the GNU Make site ( https://www.gnu.org/software/make/ ) had a sub section for clever tricks like this one.